# How to hold position of listboxitem when adding/removing items?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, listbox, scroll

I have a listbox which contains 20-50 items. All items must be sorted by unique id. 
After applying sort, my listbox scrolls at top. How to prevent that?
Sort function

```
public static void Sort<TSource, TValue>(IList<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TValue> selector) {
      for (int i = source.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
          TSource o1 = source.ElementAt(j - 1);
          TSource o2 = source.ElementAt(j);
          TValue x = selector(o1);
          TValue y = selector(o2);
          var comparer = Comparer<TValue>.Default;
          if (comparer.Compare(x, y) > 0) {
            source.Remove(o1);
            source.Insert(j, o1);
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: You an use ScollIntoView(item), if you find an item you want. Or get the ActualHeight from the ScrollViewer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only this helped

```
void loadItems(){
//load
    var t = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000) };
            t.Tick += delegate {
              _ScrollViewer.UpdateLayout();
              SomethingLoading = false;
              listmy.ScrollIntoView(listmy.Items[listmy.Items.Count - 10]);
            };
            t.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To set your ListBox focus to the last item in the list, use the following expression.

```
this.ListBox1.SelectedIndex = this.ListBox1.Items.Count - 1;
```

Comment: Yes, I tried after. Nothing happens, when I call sort function listbox scrolls at top.

Answer (score 0):

This works on Windows 7. I don't have a WP7 to test it on.

```
// Finds the last item on the screen
int index = listBox1.IndexFromPoint(1, listBox1.Height - 5);

// Sorting stuff...

// Set the selected index to the one we saved, this causes the box to scroll it into view
listBox1.SelectedIndex = index;
// Clear the selection
listBox1.ClearSelected();
```

Comment: On WP7 listbox has no IndexFromPoint method

Answer (score 0):

Extract the scrollviewer from the listBox using this function

```
    public ScrollViewer FindScrollViewer(DependencyObject parent)
    {
        var childCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (var i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
        {
            var elt = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            if (elt is ScrollViewer) return (ScrollViewer)elt;
            var result = FindScrollViewer(elt);
            if (result != null) return result;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Use this function to scroll to new item in list:

```
    private void ScrollToOnFreshLoad()
    {
        ScrollViewer scroll = FindScrollViewer(listBox);
        Int32 offset = Convert.ToInt32(scroll.VerticalOffset);

        //load new list box here

        //then do this
        listBox.ScrollIntoView(listItems[offset]);
    }
```

Note: play with the offset value till you get desired result. Hope it helps